# How do I have navigationbar buttons in the same line as the navigation bar title?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two questions.

1. In my app's main screen, I have a navigation bar with a large title and a button,
   [like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnoMU.png) I want to have the "+" button in the same line as the navigation bar title, like in the [Messages App.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFD0P.jpg)
2. I want the navigation bar in my app's detail view to look like the [Wallet App's card info screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8qyh.jpg) which has this style of navigation bar where the title is centred, and with the card on top.

How would I go about doing this?

I'm using SwiftUI on Xcode 11.4 with 13.4 as the target, if that matters.

Comment: Please put what you've tried.

Comment: Please check https://uptech.team/blog/build-resizing-image-in-navigation-bar-with-large-title

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd question, You can use this below code to make navigation bar transparent:

```
public func makeNavigationBarWithoutBorder(color: UIColor = UIColor.clear) {
    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let image = UIImage.init(color: color)
    self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
    self.navigationBar.shadowImage = image
    self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
}
```

Now for add left and right button like below.

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: Asset.greyCross.image, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: Asset.greyCross.image, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Hope this will give you the second one's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I may be able to help you out, though not with SwiftUI.

It looks like you're using `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` which I don't think Facebook is using but if you wish to continue down that path with a button to the right-hand side try this.

```
    tableView.addSubview(yourButton)
    yourButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    yourButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    yourButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
```

2) The image and title are not apart of the navigation bar. It looks like a view which is constrained below it.